# Array in success function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

Why does this code

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i]["bla"] = "check";
}
```

work perfectly, whereas the array is here, according to firebug, undefinied:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my url",
        data: "data here",
        success: function() {
            array[i]["bla"] = "check";
        }
    });
}
```

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to how closures work, the value of `i` is always going to be equal to `array.length` in the callback, because that's what it equals after the loop is done (after all, `i < array.length` is false). And that position is always undefined. You need to re-bind `i` inside the loop to make the current value "stick". Unfortunately the only way to do this in standard JS is to use yet another function, for instance:

```
for (...; i++) {
    (function(boundI) {
        // boundI is now bound to the current value of i in the current scope
        // If you want, you can call boundI just "i", but make sure you understand
        // how scopes work in JS before you do.
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function() {
                array[boundI]["bla"] = "check";
            }
        });
    })(i); // pass in the current value of the loop index which gets bound to boundI
}
```

Comment: True, with one small correction: `i` is not guaranteed to be `array.length` at each callback.  It's unpredictable, depending on when the callbacks are triggered, i.e., when the Ajax responses come.

Comment: @Mike: Asynchronous response handlers are ran in the same thread with everything else, via the same event queue as everything else. No response handler will run before the loop (and the entire current event handler) has been fully processed.

Comment: If the OP is access the array directly after the loop, he will not see any difference either.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a synchronous call:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false, //This does the magic
        url: "my url",
        data: "data here",
        success: function() {
            array[i]["bla"] = "check";
        }
    });
}
```

Or, to keep syncronicity

```
    var array = ...    
    function loadElement(i){
       if(i == array.length) return;
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my url",
            data: "data here",
            success: function() {
                array[i]["bla"] = "check";
                loadElement(i+1); 
            }
        });
    }
    loadElement(0);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers